# Read CSV file with strings to RDD spark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have input CSV file as below

```
123,john,ny,"new-emp-in"
111,rock,sf,"recently,promoted"
100,smith,la,"10.101.0129-name,string"
```

so how can i read this and created RDD?
com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 supports this, but i cannot use this.

Comment: what spark version are you using? `val df = spark.read.option("header", false).option("inferSchema", true).csv("*.csv")` works for me spark 2.0.2.

Comment: yes, but i am using 1.x :(

Comment: Apart from seriously considering to upgrade to spark2.x, and if you really cant use databrick's csv package (for mysterious reasons !) , simplest way you can try is use `textFile` method to read file and use regex to find the columns/data which contain commas between quotes and replace them something else. So this is basic data preparation operation, once you are done with that, you can use simple `rdd.map(lambda row: row.split(","))` operation to make each row as comma separated list

Comment: @Pushkr I want the commas in the data, if I replace it with something then I need to again replace it with comma. I'm not sure what to replace comma with in first stage, since fields may contain any kind of characters.

Answer (score 2):

In spark 2.0+ you can use the [`SparkSession.read`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) method to read in a number of formats, one of which is csv. Using this method you could do the following:

```
df = spark.read.csv(filename)
```

Or for an rdd just:

```
rdd = spark.read.csv(filename).rdd
```

**Update**

Having seen your comment take a look at [CSV Data Source for Apache Spark 1.x](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). I believe this was part of what lead to the read method being included in Spark 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

With older version of Spark you cannot read csv directly. But you can include Databrick's csv jar and use their Python API to achieve the same.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', 
  inferschema='true').load('cars.csv')
df.select('year', 
  'model').write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('newcars.csv')
```

Reference: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#python-api

Comment: Was this useful? Do you have any follow up questions?